# what would be the JsonPath in java for the following json

Tags: java, json, testing, jsonpath

I am doing a controller test and am testing to see if the returned json values are correct. this is my json`{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Jones",
    "phoneNumber": "0123456789",
    "jobTitle": "Software Developer",
    "companyName": "BFS",
    "industry": {
        "name": "legal"
    },
    "companySize": {
        "noOfEmployees": "1_to_10"
    },
    "accounts": [
        {
            "accountName": "TestAccount1",
            "accountNo": "123",
            "accountType": "PREPAY",
            "creditBalance": "25.00",
            "creditLimit": "500.00",
            "concurrentSubscriptionLimit": "10",
            "hitsPerSubscriptionItemLimit": "20",
            "hourlyRequestLimit": "30"
        }
    ]
}`

and my current test looks like this: `mockMvc.perform(request)
        .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstName", is("Bob")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName", is("Jones")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.phoneNumber", is("0123456789")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.jobTitle", is("Software Developer")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.companyName", is("BFS")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.industry.name", is("legal")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.companySize.noOfEmployees", is("1_to_10")))
        .andReturn();
    }`

My questions is, how would I write the jsonPath for accountName in the accounts field? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use JSON Pointer instead?

Comment: hm okay, how would i go about doing it using Json Pointer? i had a quick look and didn't manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access to the accountName value, you should use this expression :

```
$.accounts[0].accountName
```

You can also get all the accountName with this expression :

```
$.accounts[*].accountName
```

Hope it helps !